# geocoding CSV using MMQGIS and error massage

Tags: geocoding, csv, mmqgis

While geocoding a csv file using MMQGIS utility in QGIS, I provide an input and the follwing errror message pops out, what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: You're probably denied access to writing the **Not Found Output List** .csv file in your QGIS directory. Try changing the output location of this to another such as the Desktop.